# I need a base plate for my rb67 pro s

Tags: mamiya

the base plate is missing on my rb67 and I need a new one without buying a new body for one part, anyone knows where I can find one?
[image]

Comment: Is this the threaded insert that converts 3/8" to 1/4-20? If not, please add a picture of the bottom of the camera.

Comment: it is not a tripod mount for the plate, its the entire bottom of the camera, I bought the body and it didn't have one,

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a 'shopping question'. Google found one in the first hit.

Comment: +lack of research.  @StuartHunt welcome to Photo.SE! It is very much appreciated if question askers include (minimal) research in their question. If e.g. the first Google hit is not satisfactory, you can include that information in your question and people here can help you with your search.

Comment: I've found them on the first search but they are all SOLD OUT, I can not find one, if you wouldn't mind, could u send me the link?

Comment: to be clear it is not a TRIPOD MOUNT that i need it is the BASE PLATE, i haven't found one available anywhere, they are all sold out

Answer (score 1):

The camera has not been a current model for about thirty years.

It might be possible to have a base plate machined. Or perhaps 3d printed.

However, a donor camera is probably the most direct way of finding the part because it appears to be an integral part of the camera, [not an accessory](https://www.cameramanuals.org/mamiya_pdf/mamiya_rb67_pro-s_system.pdf).

If the camera requires the base plate for ordinary operation, then the camera you have is more of a parts camera than a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! the mirror ios also crooked and the focusing wheel came broken so i might just go for a donor camera

Comment: @StuartHunt it sounds like you might use your current camera as a donor for one with fewer issues.